# ANDROID SQLite SELECT x AS _id

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using the SimpleCursorAdapter that requires a collumn named "_id". 
My table doesn't have an '_id' so i did the workarround of defining the query with an "AS _id" and it works. I'm doing it with *getReadableDatabase().rawQuery()*.
I want to know if there is any other way of doing the same query but with a method, like [SQLiteQueryBuilder.query](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#buildQueryString%28boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to [create a view in your SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createview.html) database, that will use _id from the original table by an alias. Then you need to query the view which is actually a table.

Answer (score 1):

This might be possible when querying sqlite directly, but passing `col as _id` to `ContentResolver.query()` throws a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column col as _id`.

As an alternative, I would suggest creating a `view` in your sqlite database.

```
CREATE VIEW view1 AS SELECT pkid AS _id, ... FROM your_table;
```